# How to create object of type declared in generic class

Tags: python, generics, mypy, typing

I need to initialise an object of type TypeVar described in an generic class

```
class TDict(TypedDict):
   a: int


T = TypeVar("TType", bound=TDict)


class TestClass(Generic[T]):
    d: T


    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.d = TDict(a=1)
```

This cause an error

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "TDict", variable has type "T")
```

At the same time, I cannot create an object with type T. How can I create an object with type T?

upd.
I need to inherit typed dict from TDict and use it in my program. So I heed TestClass to create a dict object of inherited class

Something like this

```
class ExpandedTDict(TDict):
    b: int


t_class: TestClass[ExpandedTDict] = TestClass[ExpandedTDict]()
assert t_class.d[a] == 1
t_class.d[b] = 2


class OtherExpandedTDict(TDict):
    c: int


other_t_class: TestClass[OtherExpandedTDict] = TestClass[OtherExpandedTDict]()
assert other_t_class.d[a] == 1
other_t_class.d[c] = 2

other_t_class.d[b] = 2  # -> error
```

Comment: What is your real use case? That example code doesn't really make sense, as you are not using the parametrization of your generic class.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error ([mypy-play](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=342e629849f8770473e369e51cf5acd0)). Although technically it is a type error to assign a `TDict` object to a variable of `T` type, because `T` can be any subtype of `TDict`.

Comment: I can reproduce my error with `-> None` ([mypy-play](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=47e1683553e03111e47c2e4c2234d40b))

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the constructor call in a generic function.  That lets you specify the type without the redundancy of also specifying it as a generic type to the class.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Generic, TypedDict

class TDict(TypedDict):
   a: int

_T = TypeVar("_T", bound="TDict")

class TestClass(Generic[_T]):
    def __init__(self, type_: Type[_T]):
        self.d: _T = type_(a=1)

# This is the trick you're looking for
def new_test_class(type_: Type[_T]):
    return TestClass[_T](type_)

class ExpandedTDict(TDict):
    b: int

class OtherExpandedTDict(TDict):
    c: int

t_class = new_test_class(ExpandedTDict)
assert t_class.d['a'] == 1
t_class.d['b'] = 2

other_t_class = new_test_class(OtherExpandedTDict)
assert other_t_class.d['a'] == 1
other_t_class.d['c'] = 2

print(other_t_class.d['b'])  # -> error. reading fails as desired. assignment as in your example won't fail no matter what.
```

This also works with regular classes and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, type variables are "erased" at runtime -- you can't access `T` at runtime.

1. You can instantiate the class without providing a type to the class at all:

```py
my_class: TestClass[SubclassOfTDict] = TestClass()
```

2. You don't necessarily have a concrete class as the parameter. For example, `T` could be assigned to `Any` or to a union of classes. What do you do in that case?

What you can do is pass the dictionary into `__init__`:

```py
class TestClass(Generic[T]):
    d: T

    def __init__(self, d: T):
        self.d = d
```

However, I think you're experiencing some kind of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I don't see how it's useful to instantiate a subclass of a `TypedDict` class, given that a subclass will have additional fields. Could you explain more about your probleM?

Comment: I want to use some code like I provided in the body (I updated it). And I need to create several different ExpandedTDict and create with each of them different TestClass objects

Comment: Well, as I explained, you can't "look" at the type because it's not present at runtime. I still don't really understand what you want, but you could pass the type as a parameter: `TestClass(ExpandedTDict)`. The `__init__` needs the signature of `__init__(self, dict_type: type[T]) -> None`

Comment: Passing d as a parameter in `__init__` is possible, but it is not good to include this parameter in this method. I just need to initialise `self.d` with no arguments in the constructor. And I want `self.d` to be the same type as I further implement as a subtype of the TDict

Comment: You could create a custom metaclass that required you to initialize the class as `TestClass[TDict]()`, and then have the parameter be available as a class variable.